# How to add new content using a content type added after taxonomy access control was installed?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have added some content types to Drupal to store some custom content.
Then I installed the [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module to manage the access rights. At this point everything was working perfectly and easily.

Then I added a new content type but when I try to "add a new content", this content type doesn't appear in the list of content types.

Is this because of the Taxonomy Access Control module? Do I have to re install it?

**Note**: I also flushed the cache and performed "rebuild permissions". It appears in the admin/content type filter. but if i add content, no trace of it.

Comment: and you  try this with the user 1 (uid=1)?

Comment: Yes. I used the user 1 and with others with rights to create content.

Comment: Are you sure the new content type got created? Does it show up in `/admin/content` [Type filter](http://i.stack.imgur.com/V8FvR.jpg)?

Comment: Did you try flushing the cache?

Comment: What i did : - flush the cache and rebuild permissions. It appears in the admin/content type filter (i didn't look à this before) but if i add content, no trace of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/31601) of the [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module. Especially what it says about the **Global default** (within [Global and vocabulary defaults](https://www.drupal.org/node/31601#defaults)), i.e:

> The **global default**, at the top of the form, determines the grants the role receives for untagged nodes (including nodes with terms that are not in controlled vocabularies). Keep in mind that access is denied by default, so if you want TAC to grant a role access to untagged nodes, set the global default to allow for that grant and role.

See what happens if you adapt this default. If the issue persists, then you may want to perform [TAC troubelshooting](https://www.drupal.org/node/731850), possibly even [Troubleshooting with Devel](https://www.drupal.org/node/731850#devel).

Comment: Thank you. For the first point, i have already read this documentation (I may have understood it the wrong way though). My problem is that I have two other custom content types that work perfectly (so i don't think the TAC module is misconfigured). The only difference with the new one (as far as i believe) is that the TAC module was installed **after** these two were created but **before** the last one was. So i'll have a look at the troubleshooting pages and maybe try to uninstall the TAC and re-install it...

Comment: @Jice Just an extra check: all for your content types do have a term reference field, right? Because for a content type without such field, how would TAC know if it should yes or no grant access. Sorry of this is a stupid extra check, but one never knows ... and I bet that, in the end, it's going to turn out some config option missing somewhere (+ debugging = the art of trying to eliminate all possible causes ...). Curious to hear how it will turn out ... if you ever find it.

Comment: There is no stupid extra check ;-). Thank you for your help. I'm rather new to Drupal and I may have forgotten some stupid thing. But in this case, there is a term reference field. But this term reference points a new taxonomy (created after the TAC module installation). Another thing is that the label of this field is Tag which is the same as another filed in another content type. Machine names are different but label are identical.

Comment: @Jice I don't expect (hope!) that using the same labels would cause any issues. Not sure if it would help, but I would try to eliminate the possibility that your issue might have to do with the fact that that taxonomy is "new" (created after TAC was installed). This by (again) disable / uninstall  / enable TAC.

Comment: I'll try this but it will take some time as i have to reinstall it on my dev machine.

Comment: I disabled TAC module and desinstall it and the new content type still doesn't appear. So it doesn't seem to be linked with TAC.

Comment: I assume you also performed a "clear cache", and "rebuild permissions", if it doesn't help, it doesn't hurt either ... If that's the case, you've made a major progress in debugging: TAC has nothing to do with your issue, right?

Comment: In a way yes, TAC is innocent. But i still don't understand. Thank you for your help anyway.